# Canceling a delay in Arduino C/C++

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

## The Problem!

My problem is that I'm making a clock, and I want to make it able to change the time with a keypad, but I think this line of code to delay for 60 seconds, `delay(60000);` interferes.

## My Code

This is my code with @tuyau2poil's implementation:

```
/*
 * 7 Segment Clock
 * Created by SniverDaBest
 * Date: 2/9/23
*/

// Include the 7-segment display library:
#include <TM1637Display.h>
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#define CLK 5
#define DIO 6

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;
int buzzer = 3;
bool clockStarted = false;
unsigned long timerSec;
int time = 1200;
int secTime = 0;
char result;

char buttons[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},  // 1st row
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},  // 2nd row
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},  // 3rd row
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}   // 4th row
};
 
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 4};
byte colPins[COLS] = {10, 11, 12, 13};  // reassigned two of the column pins

// This is useful for power https://www.amazon.com/Printer-Adapter-Convert-Connector-Compatible/dp/B092C5DNSF/ref=sr_1_10?adgrpid=1335908033757253&hvadid=83494457602384&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=43722&hvnetw=o&hvqmt=e&hvtargid=kwd-83495174141932%3Aloc-190&hydadcr=18004_10780277&keywords=usb-c+to+usb+b&qid=1675997137&sr=8-10
 
// Create display object of type TM1637Display:
TM1637Display disp = TM1637Display(CLK, DIO);
Keypad kp = Keypad(makeKeymap(buttons), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
 
// Create array that turns all segments on:
const uint8_t all_on[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff}; // 0xff is a hexidecimal number whose binary
                                                 // representation is all ones
 
// Create array that turns all segments off:
const uint8_t blank[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  disp.clear();
  delay(1000);
  // Set the brightness:
  disp.setBrightness(7);
  // All segments on:
  disp.setSegments(all_on);
  delay(2000);
  disp.clear();
  delay(1000);
  timerSec = millis();
}

void runEverySecond() {
  timerSec = millis();
  secTime++;
  if (secTime > 60) {
    runEveryMinute();
  }
}

void runEveryMinute() {
  secTime = 0;
  if (result == '1') {
    if (time <= 1259) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 1260) {
      time = 100;
    }
    if (time <= 159) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 160) {
      time = 200;
    }
    if (time <= 259) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 260) {
      time = 300;
    }
    if (time <= 359) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 360) {
      time = 400;
    }
    if (time <= 459) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 460) {
      time = 500;
    }
    if (time <= 559) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 560) {
      time = 600;
    }
    if (time <= 659) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 660) {
      time = 700;
    }
    if (time <= 759) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 760) {
      time = 800;
    }
    if (time <= 859) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 860) {
      time = 900;
    }
    if (time <= 959) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 960) {
      time = 1000;
    }
    if (time <= 1059) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 1060) {
      time = 1100;
    }
    if (time <= 1159) {
      time++;
    }
    if (time == 1160) {
      time = 1200;
    }
  }
  else if (result == '2'){
    if (time <= 1259) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 1199) {
      time = 1159;
    }
    if (time <= 159) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 160) {
      time = 1000;
    }
    if (time <= 259) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 260) {
      time = 300;
    }
    if (time <= 359) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 360) {
      time = 400;
    }
    if (time <= 459) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 460) {
      time = 500;
    }
    if (time <= 559) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 560) {
      time = 600;
    }
    if (time <= 659) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 660) {
      time = 700;
    }
    if (time <= 759) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 760) {
      time = 800;
    }
    if (time <= 859) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 860) {
      time = 900;
    }
    if (time <= 959) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 960) {
      time = 1000;
    }
    if (time <= 1059) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 1060) {
      time = 1100;
    }
    if (time <= 1159) {
      time = time - 1;
    }
    if (time == 1160) {
      time = 1200;
    }
  }
  for (time <= 1259; time++;) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000); 
  }
  for (time = 100; time <= 159; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 200; time <= 259; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 300; time <= 359; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 400; time <= 459; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 500; time <= 559; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 600; time <= 659; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 700; time <= 759; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 800; time <= 859; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 900; time <= 959; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 1000; time <= 1059; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
  for (time = 1100; time <= 1159; time++) {
    disp.showNumberDecEx(time, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
    delay(60000);
  }
}

void loop() {
  result = kp.getKey();
  if (millis() - timerSec > 1000) {
    runEverySecond();
  }
}
```

## What I did to try and fix my problem

I tried searching Arduino forms posts, but found nothing. I tried searching for some other posts here, but no luck. There also is no command like `cancelDelay();` or `resetDelay();`. Help would be most appreciated!

Comment: remove the delay and do the timing with technique shown in the BlinkWithoutDelay example

Answer (score 0):

use millis() : this function return mS from last powerOn and is incremented... every mS.
You can then create timers without blocking loop execution.

update : I dont understand why you complicate things as much: basically just create a few simple functions to increase or decrease hours and minutes (integer vars), then, to display time,
multiplie hour by 100, which shifts it from 2 digits to the left, and add it to minutes. (I chose cross keys on the keyboard but you can choose others).
Without keypad intervention, the display changes time automatically every minute.
I dont have necessary harware and time to test but I think it must work.
I added some comments for your understanding

**keypad keys assignment**

- 8 = increase hours
- 2 = decrease hours
- 4 = decrease minutes
- 6 = increase minutes

*time go from 00:00 to 23:59*

```
#include <TM1637Display.h>
//#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#define CLK 5
#define DIO 6

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;
int buzzer = 3;
bool clockStarted = false;
unsigned long timerSec;
int secTime = 0;
char result;

int H, M; //hours, minutes

char buttons[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},  // 1st row
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},  // 2nd row
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},  // 3rd row
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}   // 4th row
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 4};
byte colPins[COLS] = {10, 11, 12, 13};  // reassigned two of the column pins

// Create display object of type TM1637Display:
TM1637Display disp = TM1637Display(CLK, DIO);
Keypad kp = Keypad(makeKeymap(buttons), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

// Create array that turns all segments on:
const uint8_t all_on[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff}; // 0xff is a hexidecimal number whose binary
// representation is all ones

// Create array that turns all segments off:
const uint8_t blank[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  disp.clear();
  delay(1000);
  // Set the brightness:
  disp.setBrightness(7);
  // All segments on:
  disp.setSegments(all_on);
  delay(2000);
  disp.clear();
  delay(1000);
  timerSec = millis();
}

void loop() {
  readKeypad();
  if (millis() - timerSec > 999) { //tick when exceed 999mS = every seconds
    runEverySecond();
  }
}

void readKeypad() {
  result = kp.getKey();

  if (result) { //key pressed
    if (result == '8') increaseHour();
    if (result == '2') decreaseHour();
    if (result == '6') increaseMinute();
    if (result == '4') decreaseMinute();
    delay(40); //small delay to avoid key repeating - change for your convenient
  }
}


void increaseHour() {
  if (H > 23) H = 0; //if hour > 23, hour restart from 0
  H++;           //else hour simply incremented
}

void decreaseHour() {
  if (H < 0) H = 23;
  H--;
}

void increaseMinute() {
  if (M > 59) M = 0;
  M++;
}

void decreaseMinute() {
  if (M < 0) M = 59;
  H--;
}

void incrementTime() { //call every minutes
  increaseMinute();
  if (M == 0) { //occur every hours : If minute exceeds 59 restart from 0
    increaseHour(); //if hour exceeds 23 restart from 0
  }
}

void runEverySecond() {
  timerSec = millis();
  secTime++;
  if (secTime > 59) { //ticks every minute
    runEveryMinute();
  }
}

void runEveryMinute() {
  secTime = 0;
  incrementTime();
  updateDisplay();
}

void updateDisplay() {
  int fullTime = H * 100 + M; // ex for H=5 and M=15 fullTime = 515 so display = 05:15
  disp.showNumberDecEx(fullTime, 0b11100000, false, 4, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble integrating this in my code. I have all the variables created, but I had to move my keypad result variable outside my loop function, while still updating it in the loop function. That may make a difference, maybe not.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Just put my code on the question.